# How do I resolve a #define issue for cross platform development on android and ios?

Tags: android, iphone, c++, ios, ipad

I'm trying to do cross-platform development for android and ios. I'm writing the code in C++ but as I'm starting out I'm seeing that xcode is inserting the following `#define` in the headers:

```
#ifndef tutorial_FloatMatrix_h
#define tutorial_FloatMatrix_h

#endif
```

Tutorial is the name of the project and `FloatMatrix.h` the name of the header. This doesn't seem like it would be portable. I don't normally see the project name prepended to the header name in this kind of `#define`. Is there a way to make the intent of this `#define` work in ios and android? Also what is this `#define` trying to perform and does it have a name (i.e. what would I google)?

Answer (score 2):

Why wouldn't it be portable? As long as 'tutorial_FloatMatrix_h' is a unique name, it should work fine with any C/C++ compiler. Also, the define is called a header guard, it's purpose is to insure that multiple copies of a header aren't included by a single translation unit,( eg. .cpp file).

Comment: Also sometimes called 'include guard'.

Answer (score 1):

This is a usual way to limit multiple header inclusion from C source codes.
These codes should be portable to any C compiler.